# Why is my NSManagedObject not KVC compliant?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5, key-value-coding

I'm attempting to use KVC to retrieve the value of a property of a custom NSManagedObject entity built using Core data. I'm getting a UnknownKeyException when trying to access a property a few levels deep, and for the life of me i can't figure out why...

The root entity is called "Catch". it has a number of properties: weight, length, etc. It also has a to-one relationship to another entity called "Species". Species has a name property defined as NSString.

So:

```
//this will output the species name (i.e. "Brook Trout")
NSLog(@"Catch.species.name = %@", catch.species.name);

//this will throw a NSUnknownKeyException
NSLog(@"Catch.species.name = %@", [catch valueForKey:@"species.name"]);

//but this works...!?
Species *species = (Species*)[catch valueForKey:@"species"];
NSLog(@"Species.name = %@", species.name);
```

The specific exception details are:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Catch is not key value coding-compliant for the key "species.name".'

Does anyone who understands this stuff better than me know what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `-valueForKeyPath:` instead of `-valueForKey:` for a chain of keys i.e. "species.name" in this case.